# How to make width of <select> element proportional to <div> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Now, I would like to make width of my select element, let's say 80% of its parent div ( div#queries). Is there anyway to do it?

```
<div id="flowchart-left-panel">

                <div id ="queries">
                    <h3>Queries</h3>
                    <select class="query-list" size="20">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="filters">
                    <h3>Filters</h3>
                    <select class="filter-list" size="10">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: in css you can specify the width  attribute.

Comment: `<select class="query-list" size="20" style="width:80%;">`

Comment: @Lal yes, but do you know how could I do that ? I mean I know that I can do something like that width=100px but, what should I do if I want to do it in terms of width of div element?

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f45jx1pq/).. is that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, with CSS.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYYGvG

```
#queries, #filters{
 width: 300px; 
}

select{
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: so, do I have to fix the size of div element before?

Comment: Or use a max or min width. Or don't set a width on the parent and only set a width on the select.